# Get Api Data using Guzzle client

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am Trying to call data from API which working fine in Postman and jquery , it has a API key name "APP_KEY" which must be sent as a header or else the data of the API can not be accessed ,I am trying to get the data using Guzzle HTTP Client But it is not sending the header,

Here is the Header that needs to be passed in:

```
APP_KEY=>QAWLhIK2p5
```

Here is the Controller Part:

```
$client = new Client();
      $body['headers']= array('APP_KEY'=>'QAWLhIK2p5');
      $response = $client->GET('http://localhost:1080/busy/public/api/material',$body);
      //dd($response->getStatusCode());

      print_r($data = $response->getResponse()->getContents());
```

Just tell me please how can I send the header with the Link to API

Any Help would be highly appreciated

Here is the Postman ss[image]

Comment: can you include postman code which is working fine in this case, also normally `api_key` is send as `body` or inside `authorization` header. Also which `api` you are trying to consume(any third party service).

Comment: url that you're using in postman and code differs

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64070737/multi-curl-with-values-from-mysql-column/64071243#64071243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use guzzle as a tag as well, I would have answered that day, you need to change your code,

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;


public function yourFunction()
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $guzzleResponse = $client->get(
                'http://localhost:1080/busy/public/api/material', [
                'headers' => [
                    'APP_KEY'=>'QAWLhIK2p5'
                ],
            ]);
        if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody(),true);
        }
        
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        // you can catch here 400 response errors and 500 response errors
        // see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040436/guzzle-handle-400-bad-request/25040600
    } catch(Exception $e){
        //other errors 
    }
}
```

It is as easy as that, for more info, just see [docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers)